# Update an SQL table through PHP when a customer makes a Paypal Subscription

Tags: php, html, sql, session, paypal

I am trying to make it so that when a user subscribes via a paypal subscription, I will be able to update the subscription date onto the SQL users table. I can subscribe on paypal no problem, but the database is not updating the date. The connect file works fine, I can update the database in other ways, it's just the form doesn't start the "POST" code.

```
<?php 
$page_title = 'Subscribe' ;
include('includes/navuser.php');
# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Check form submitted.
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' )
{
# Connect to the database.
require ('includes/connect_db.php'); 

# Initialize an error array.
$errors = array();

# On insert to payments database table.
if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
{
$q = "UPDATE users SET subdate = NOW() WHERE username = 
'{$_SESSION[username]}'";
 $r = @mysqli_query ( $link, $q ) ;


 $w = "UPDATE users SET subdate = DATEADD(yyyy,1,subdate) WHERE username = 
 '{$_SESSION[username]}'";
 $s = @mysqli_query ( $link, $w ) ;

# Close database connection.
# mysqli_close($link); 
}  
}
?>

 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 
 target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" 
value="JHUF6WR4677MN">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
```

Thank you

Comment: What do error reporting and `mysqli_error($link)` reveal? This once you've removed the `@` error suppressor that is.

Comment: I don't see any of the form's inputs used anywhere.